# How to set settings.xml in linux

Tags: linux, maven

I want to set maven settings as an environment variable in linux , every maven goal will be runned with this settings without adding  --settings

Comment: What kind of env variable and why? The settings.xml is located in your home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` why do you need an environment variable ? You don't need any `--settings ..` if you use the default location..

Comment: The environment is deployed on cloud

Comment: And why do you need that in your build environment ?

Comment: Cause I run mvn goals there

Comment: In the deployment environment? There should be deployed only the executable code but not the build system... Also don't you use a CI solution (Jenkins, CircleCI, Drone, etc whatever?)